# How can I reach a value from an array and update it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm working at this project and I have users which have positive ranking. But I want to store others users id in an array which hit that "positive ranking button". I'm working with Mongoose and NodeJs.

I created the User Schema which contains the array and I searched for that user in my database, I get the user, but I'm stuck here, I don't know if I have to use a "for" to reach all array values or how do I check if the user has already "positive ranked" him.

This is my postPositiveRank function

```
exports.postPositiveRank = (req,res,next) =>{
const targetUser = req.body.targetUserId;
const loggedInUser = req.session.user._id;

User.findOne({"_id": targetUser}, function(err, process) {
    for( let i = 0; i< process.positiveRanked.length;i++)
    {
        if(loggedInUser.equals(process.positiveRanked[i]))
        {
            //
        }
        else {
            process.positiveRanked.push(loggedInUser);
            process.positiveRanked.save();
        }
    }
})
}
```

And my User Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema =  new Schema({
firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
lastname: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
age: {
    type: Number,
    required:true
},
occupation: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
county: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
country: {
    type:String,
    required: true,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
rate:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
},
positiveRanked: [],
negativeRanked: []

});



module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I want that loggedInUser to be searched on the array even if it's positiveRanking or negativeRanking and if it is found to get back on the page with a message (I handle that ), and if it's not found to be added to the array.
I appreciate if you can help me, I hope I explained well.

Comment: I have a Question does every user in the DB has positive rank and negative rank arrays

Comment: yes they do have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your schema for `positiveRanked` please change that. You can use `findIndex` method on arrays to getIndex of the user you want to search if found it will return the index of the user in that array if not it will return -1 by this way you can avoid using for loop. I suggest using async/await because this is the better approach where you can keep your code clean and robust. If it did not work please let me know

```
exports.postPositiveRank = (req,res,next) =>{
const targetUser = req.body.targetUserId;
const loggedInUser = req.session.user._id;

User.findOne({"_id": targetUser}, function(err, process) {
     const index=process.postitiveRanked.findIndex(id=>id===loggedInUser)
     if(index!==-1)
     {
       // user found
     }
     else{
      process.positiveRanked.push(loggedInUser);
      process.save()
     }

})
}
```

Using Async/await

```
exports.postPositiveRank = async (req,res,next) =>{
const targetUser = req.body.targetUserId;
const loggedInUser = req.session.user._id;
   try{
        let user = await User.findOne({"_id": targetUser})
        const index=user.postitiveRanked.findIndex(id=>id===loggedInUser)
        if(index!==-1)
          {
           // user found
          }
        else{
           user.positiveRanked.push(loggedInUser);
           await user.save()
         }
      }
   catch(error){
        console.log(error)
      }
}
```

Comment: I edited the post with the changed Schema, tell me if it's okay, please!

Comment: why did you made arrays empty

Comment: they are supposed to be empty, I guess, I don't want any value in there at the beggining

Comment: I got this error when I try to put a request " TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined " I know the arrays are empty, but that they should be

Comment: Then check  if `array.length!==0 ` then only find index if not directly push user id to array

Comment: Once check in the DB when you are creating the user the array is getting created or not. If it is not getting created then you will get cannot find undefined error

Comment: I checked, it is created